# can be the same thing without using the tween.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, tween.js

I want to rewrite code below without the use of a tween.js

**svg animation ／ current code (used the tween.js)**

```
var path1 = document.getElementById('path1');
var path2 = document.getElementById('path2');
var pathLength = path2.getTotalLength();
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween({ offset: 1 }).to({ offset: pathLength }, 1000 )
  .onUpdate(function(){
    path1.setAttribute('startOffset', this.offset);
  }).repeat(5)
  .start();
animate = function(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  TWEEN.update();
}
animate();
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me why you get the `pathLength` from `path2` but use this value to animate `startOffset` of `path1`. I'd find a more complete example helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes can make a function like this one to calculate the time of each step:

```js
var path1 = document.getElementById('path1');
var path2 = document.getElementById('path2');
var pathLength = path2.getTotalLength();

function setOffset(base, target, duration){
    for (let index = base; index <= target; index++) {
        setTimeout( ()=>{
            base.setAttribute('startOffset', index);
            //console.log(`Index ${index} time: ${index * duration / target}ms`);
        }, index * target / duration)
    }
}

setOffset(1, pathLength, 1000)
```

For a smooth animation you should add more step on the loop :

Example for 60 frame per second.

```js
var path1 = document.getElementById('path1');
var path2 = document.getElementById('path2');
var pathLength = path2.getTotalLength();

function setOffset(base, target, duration) {
    for (let index = 0; index <= target * 60; index++) {
        setTimeout( ()=>{
            // base.setAttribute('startOffset', index / 60);
            console.log(`Index ${index / 60} time: ${index * target / duration}ms`);
        }, index * target / duration)
    }
}

setOffset(1, pathLength, 1000)
```